# $http get request with form

Tags: angularjs, forms, http, get, parameters

I simply can't find a suitable answer to my problem. I am rather new to Angular and have a simple problem with a $http request. I have a form set up where a user can type in a place and a time and for example a number of people.

Now I want to get data from my server using these three user inputs to provide a answer to the user request.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="bla1" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.input1">
<input type="text" placeholder="bla2" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.input2">
<input type="text" placeholder="bla3" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.input3">
```

Obviously, I can now POST them all to formatData on ng-submit. But I want to use this information to retrieve data and to make a `get $http` request.

I believe the  `params` and `data` attribute are the ones to change and to exploit.

Can someone explain to me how that would work or how in general a form's input can be used to specify $http requests?

Thanks a lot to all of you!

Comment: So you want to use an $http.get(url) function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first at all you should read this [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in order to get a better idea about it;

For using Get you will have to build your query string with your input that you will add after your base url.

```
 var completeUrl = baseUrl + "?input1="+ formData.input1 
                     + "&input2=" + formData.input2 //and the same for input 3
 $http({method: 'GET', url: completeUrl}).
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // here data contains all informations returned by the server
 }).
 error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //In case your server respond with a 4XX or 5XX error code
 });
```

You can call this piece of code simply by putting it in a scope function and call with an ng-submit

```
$scope.submitFunction = function() { .. }
```

And in your template

```
<form ng-submit="submitFunction()" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` or `query` function based on whether the response is an object or array.

`$http.get(url,{params:{'item1':formData.input1,'item2':formData.input2,'item3':formData.input3}});`

This data would go in querystring.

`url?item1=data&item2=data&item3=data`

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use `$http.get(url,{value1: your.form.input})` to make the http get with your custom values!